# What does a retarding field energy analyzer measure?

Tags: plasma-physics, instrument

According to [1], p.58, the current collected by a retarding field analyzer is:

$$I= qA \int^\infty_{v_{min}} vf(v)dv $$

where $q$ is the electron charge magnitude (here singly charged ions are assumed), $A$ is the effective collecting area of the probe, $v$ is the velocity of an ion perpendicular to the plane of the RFEA head, $f(v)$ is the **velocity** distribution function of the ions (IVDF), and $v_{min}$ is the
minimum ion velocity given by:

$$v_{min} = \sqrt{\frac{2qV_D}{M_i}}$$

with $M_i$ the ion mass, and $V_D$ the discriminator voltage.

Now, according to [2], the collected current is:

$$I = -\frac{q^2n_iA}{M} \int^\infty_{qV_D} g(E)dE$$

Where $g(E)$ is the ion **energy** distribution function (IEDF).

So we have the same instrument, some say it measures the IVDF, others the IEDF. I know the two are related (because $E = \frac{1}{2} M_i v^2$ = qV), but I just don't understand:

- How are these expressions of the current first obtained?
- Why is the density of the ions $n_i$ present in the second equation and not the first?
- How do I go from the IEDF to the IVDF (and reciprocally)?

[1] Lafleur T., Helicon Wave Propagation in Low Diverging Magnetic Fields, https://openresearch-repository.anu.edu.au/handle/1885/8676

[2] Ferda B., Retarding Potential Analyzer Theory and Design, http://w3.pppl.gov/ppst/docs/ferda.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How are these expressions of the current first obtained?

The expression for current density, $\mathbf{j}$, is a well known thing, which in the macroscopic form is given by:
$$
\mathbf{j} = \sum_{s} \ q_{s} \ n_{s} \ \mathbf{v}_{s}
$$
where $q_{s}$ is the charge of species $s$, $n_{s}$ is the number density of species $s$, and $\mathbf{v}_{s}$ is the bulk flow velocity of species $s$, i.e., the first velocity [moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) of the particle velocity distribution function (e.g., [Maxwellian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution)).

A retarding potential analyzer (RPA) is basically a mixture of a [Faraday Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cup) and a [Langmuir probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langmuir_probe).  It measures energy per charge, much like a Faraday cup.  A detailed derivation explaining how one finds current densities can be found in the link to J. Kasper's PhD thesis on the [Wind spacecraft's](https://wind.nasa.gov/inst_info.php#SWE_i_Docs) NASA webpage.

The first integral expression will yield a speed times a density, i.e., the density is included within the expression for $f\left(v\right)$.  The form of $g\left(E\right)$ in the second integral expression should really be in terms of energy per charge, but one can differentiate it to find:
$$
g\left(\frac{E}{q}\right) = - \frac{ M }{ q^{2} \ n_{i} \ A } \ \frac{ dI }{ dV }
$$

> Why is the density of the ions $n_{i}$ present in the second equation and not the first?

As I said above, $n_{i}$ is contained within $f\left(v\right)$.  From a simple dimensional analysis, one can see this must be true for the units to work out.

> How do I go from the IEDF to the IVDF (and reciprocally)?

You just use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) and know that:
$$
f\left(E\right) \ dE = f\left(\mathbf{p}\right) d^{3}p
$$
where $\mathbf{p}$ is the three vector momentum and in the nonrelativistic limit, $E = \tfrac{p^{2}}{2 \ m}$.

There are detailed steps given in the Wikipedia article on the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) that show how to go from one form to another.  However, be careful as I do not think the general form of $f\left(v\right)$ is the same as is implied by $g\left(E\right)$.